# QString::fromUtf8(str) and \u encoded character sequences

Tags: c++, encoding, utf-8, qstring

I was using string literals with `\u` encoded sequences, for passing them to `QString::fromUtf8`, like in `QString::fromUtf8("Precio (\u20AC/k)");`, with success, but, struggling my mind a bit, and reading cppreference and other sources, I have not clear how is the `\u20AC` sequence translated in binary.

In other words, what is `QString::fromUtf8` receaving in substitution of the `\u20AC` sequence? The UTF-8 representation of the `20AC` codepoint? Its UTF-16 representation? Or what?

The most majority of the sources I've read says it is translated to its UTF-16 representation, which means that I'm doing wrong when passing that string to `fromUtf8`, however, it has always worked fine.

Am I doing to right thing or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encoding of the unprefixed string literal `"..."` is implementation-defined. On many non-Windows compilers it defaults to UTF-8, although it may sometimes be changed; for GCC this switch is `-fexec-charset` ([docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Invocation.html)).

To get UTF-8 encoding of a string literal independent of the execution character set, C++11 introduced `u8"..."` ([cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal))

Comment: Even if is there no Unicode escape sequences? So, a pure-ASCII unprefixed literal string like `"hello"` could be UTF-16 encoded?

Comment: @Peregring-lk no, UTF-16 is not permitted as the multibyte encoding of the  execution character set. It may be used as the wide: that weird compiler (Visual Studio) where wchar_t is 16 bit might use it as the encoding of `L"hello"`

Comment: Ok, so, the encoding of a unprefixed string literal could depend of their contents, isn't it? If a string contains only the execution character set, it is ASCII encoded (= UTF-8, = ISO-8859-1, etc), but if it contains other characters, the encoding of these particular string is implementation-defined. Isn't it?

Comment: @Peregring-lk no, it doesn't depend on content, it's one commandline option for all string literals.

Comment: Ok, but, then, I deduced that, although implementation-defined, it must be an ASCII-compatible encoding, isn't it?

Comment: @Peregring-lk not sure what you mean by "ASCII-based", but the two restrictions are: all 96 characters of the basic charset have single'byte representations and '0'-'9' appear in that order, so you can `c-'0'`